# How Can I generate a crystal reports using 3 tables?

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, report

I have 3 tables:

`Store (Store_Id, Store_Name, Store_Location)`

`Bike(Store_Id, Bike_Id,Bike_Model, Bike_Price)`

`Parts(Store_Id, Bike_Id, Part_Id, Part_Description, Part_Price)`

The `Store` is related to the `Bike` using `Store_Id`, the Bike parts is related to the `Bike` using `bike_id`. Each bike is assembled with different parts.

I want to create report that displays all the stores, bikes, and the all the bike parts used on a bike that has "Pink streamers in the description.

I honestly don't know where to start.

Please take in consideration that this database can contains thousands of bikes.

Comment: very basic question where google can get you with many results. [Try this Link](http://csharp.net-informations.com/crystal-reports/csharp-crystal-reports-multiple-tables.htm)

Comment: youtube has quite a few introductory videos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, this is a very basic question and reading some of the basics can give you the help you need.

To answer the question: in the Database Expert you will see your 3 tables. Link them together by dragging and dropping the related fields on each other. ie. link Store.Store_ID --> Bike.Store_ID --> and Bike.Bike_ID --> Parts.Bike_ID.

In the record selection formula set the description value: {parts.part_description} = "Pink Streamers".

This will give you all stores and the bikes in those stores that have "Pink Streamers"